# Sinch register again for Notifications after unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken

Tags: ios, push-notification, voip, sinch, pushkit

I am using Sinch with ManagedPush to receive notifications for VoIP via PushKit. In my app I have three possible states:

- Online
- Offline
- "Not available for incoming calls, but I can make calls"

The user can change this state at any time during the App session.

Following documentation:
https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/ios/#unregisterapushdevicetoken

I am using `unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken` as well as `stopListeningOnActiveConnection`

This seems to work to get the person not to receive incoming calls and still having the client active to make calls. Where I am having issues is on setting the user back online. The active connection works, but I can't seem to be able to register again for the notifications, to receive the call when the app is in background.

Questions like [Sinch SDK - How to logout user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514226/sinch-sdk-how-to-logout-user) don't solve how to put the user back online.

I have considered using the SinchService component https://github.com/sinch/SinchService-iOS but I can see from the code that the logout functionality terminates the client. And I am interested in not terminating the client, but stop receiving notifications and then receving them again on the same session.

What I have tried:

Not available for incomming calls button does:

```
[_client stopListeningOnActiveConnection];
[_client unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken];
```

Online button does:

```
[_client startListeningOnActiveConnection];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

The reason I am calling registerForRemoteNotifications is to force the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` delegate method to be called so I can call the Managed Push to register again for notifications. I thought that might do the trick but it didn't.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    [self.push application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

Most likely this doesn't work because this goes through PushKit and the way to register is different.

As workaround that works for me is recreating the client when the user switches to online status back:

```
[_client terminateGracefully];
_client = nil;
[self initSinchClientWithUserId:[BCDataProvider loggedInUser].callerId];
```

Is there any way I can get back on being registered for VoIP notifications, after a unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken without having to recreate the client?

Thanks!!

Comment: are you using managed push or rolling your own push server?

Comment: Hi, I am using managed push

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, basically you need to achieve VOIP, by online / offline etc you need to manage user to allow for call or not.

You can use socket architecture, which keeps broandcast user is online / offline, so on that basis you can manage to allow for call or not.

If you are working with VOIP, then below method has to be in use.

```
-(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type
{
     ///tell the Sinch SDK about the push token so we can 
     ///give that to users that want to call this user.
    [_client registerPushNotificationData:credentials.token];
}
```

Below mentioned method will not be in use.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

  
}
```

Using push notification, will always provide you new unique device token, so once you unregistered for offline, then again for online you would not be able to register with same device token.

Using push kit( Silent push notification ) you will always get same device token registering after unregistered.

Comment: Hi Hasya,
Thank you for your response! Since I am using Managed Push, as far as I understand, I shouldn't be having to call `didUpdatePushCredentials` since this is done in the Managed Push.

I am using the method `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` following the [documentation](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-managed-push/). But, as I said, most likely this didn't have anything to do since this was going through PushKit.

Let me know if I can give any more information :)