# How to switch between 2 users on the same device with Sinch APIs

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I have implemented Sinch APIs in my app, but i am not able to " log out " or switch between 2 users on the same device. the "logged out" user keep receiving incomming call( but not able to answer ) even I use unregisterManagePush() method. I made a query on Sinch's support page. But the support team told me to read the docs again. But I did exactly what the docs says.this is my code:

```
if (MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient!=null) {
      MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
      MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.unregisterManagedPush();
      MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.terminateGracefully();
      MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient=null; }
```

**UPDATE 1: CODE I HAVE TRIED**

```
 if (MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient!=null) {
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.unregisterManagedPush();
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.terminateGracefully();
       }


 if (MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient!=null) {
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.unregisterManagedPush();
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.terminate();
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient=null; }



 if (MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient!=null) {
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.unregisterManagedPush();
          MyFirebaseMessaging.sinchClient.terminate();
      }
```

=> They are all dose not work at all. Sinch keep call the previous user who logged out.

Comment: this is the link i have read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514226/sinch-sdk-how-to-logout-user

Comment: dotn set it to null, and make sure you test this with a new user since you may have called it with terminate so there is still pushprofiles on that username

Comment: I have logged in a new user. but it still call the old user. I will try again. thanks

Comment: would you please tell me what happen if I set sinch=null ? thanks

Comment: @TrầnQuốcTrung found any solution?